# electric potential produced by a lone point charge

Tags: potential-energy

I have been looking for the answer for this a question regarding the electric potential of a lone point charge. I am not understanding the material regarding this concept. My question about this concept is whether The electric potential is zero at the exact location of that charge and either always positive or always negative everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The potential of a lone point charge $q$ is

$$V(r)=-\frac{kq}{r}$$

for a distance $r$ from that charge. At the exact location of that charge, it is undefined.